# How can I make a macro in Excel workbook tab to open MS Project and copy reference cells

Tags: excel, vba, reference, ms-project

**Situation**: Our company has an Open Issues list we use for individual parts during trialing/launching a program.  The program has its own Excel document, and each part has its own tab in that document for a running list of that specific part.  It has recently been proposed that we track how long issues are open using MS Project.  I can take the information from our Excel tab and manually copy it into Project to show what we want, and I can have Project automatically update linked sources if it is 1:1 Excel sheet to Project sheet, but we only need 1 Project sheet at a time, and they need to update based on the open tab of the workbook, so the reference changes based on what part we're looking at.

**Goal**: I am looking for macro code for either/both Excel and Project that can run based on a single click that will take the reference cells in Excel copy over to Project.

So the users will open Excel and go to the tab of the part they want a chart of in Project.  They will then be able to click a button in that tab that 1) opens the formatted Project file 2) selects specific cells on that Excel tab to copy over to Project [for example, in Excel lines BE60:BI60 will copy over into line 1 of Project, BE67:BI67 to line 2, so on].  I can get the macro to open Project easily enough from Excel, but am struggling on where to even begin on copying the link source based on current tab.

The solved code I've went with is below:

```
    Sub UpdateProject()

    Dim projApp As MSProject.Application

    On Error Resume Next
    Set projApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
    If projApp Is Nothing Then
        Set projApp = New MSProject.Application
    End If
    projApp.Visible = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    projApp.FileOpenEx "C:\[File Location]\[File Name].mpp"

    Dim wst As Worksheet
    Set wst = ActiveSheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wst.Range("D60")
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = rng.Row

    Do While lRow >= 60 And rng.Column = 4 And IsDate(wst.Cells(lRow, 7).Value)

        Dim taskName As String
        taskName = wst.Cells(lRow, 57) ' column BE
        If Len(taskName) > 0 Then
            ' find task in project schedule
            projApp.Find Field:="Name", Test:="equals", Value:=taskName
            Dim t As MSProject.Task
            If projApp.ActiveCell = taskName Then
                Set t = projApp.ActiveCell.Task

            Else    ' did not find the task, so add it
                Set t = projApp.ActiveProject.Tasks.Add(taskName)
            End If
            t.Start = wst.Cells(lRow, 59).Value         ' column BG
            t.Finish = wst.Cells(lRow, 60).Value        ' column BH
            t.ResourceNames = wst.Cells(lRow, 61).Value ' column BI
        End If

        ' find next trial
        Set rng = wst.UsedRange.Find(What:="Trial Date", After:=rng, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        lRow = rng.Row
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that opens the MS Project file from Excel and updates the schedule from the active tab in the Excel file.

The trick is to use the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.find) method of the Project Application object to find the task, then set a [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task) object variable to make updating the fields simple. Don't bother updating the [Duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.duration) field as that will be calculated based on the Start and Finish.

```
Sub UpdateProject()

    Dim projApp As MSProject.Application

    On Error Resume Next
    Set projApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
    If projApp Is Nothing Then
        Set projApp = New MSProject.Application
    End If
    projApp.Visible = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    projApp.FileOpenEx "C:\[File Location]\[File Name].mpp"

    Dim wst As Worksheet
    Set wst = ActiveSheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wst.Range("D60")
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = rng.Row

    Do While lRow >= 60 And rng.Column = 4 And IsDate(wst.Cells(lRow, 7).Value)

        Dim taskName As String
        taskName = wst.Cells(lRow, 57) ' column BE
        If Len(taskName) > 0 Then
            ' find task in project schedule
            projApp.Find Field:="Name", Test:="equals", Value:=taskName
            Dim t As MSProject.Task
            If projApp.ActiveCell = taskName Then
                Set t = projApp.ActiveCell.Task

            Else    ' did not find the task, so add it
                Set t = projApp.ActiveProject.Tasks.Add(taskName)
            End If
            t.Start = wst.Cells(lRow, 59).Value         ' column BG
            t.Finish = wst.Cells(lRow, 60).Value        ' column BH
            t.ResourceNames = wst.Cells(lRow, 61).Value ' column BI
        End If

        ' find next trial
        Set rng = wst.UsedRange.Find(What:="Trial Date", After:=rng, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        lRow = rng.Row
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: The first part works, up through projApp.FileOpenEx.  The code after that will run, but nothing happens - the Project sheet remains blank.

Comment: Since your code opened an existing file, this code is designed to *update* the schedule and thus presumes tasks already exist. Make sure you have tasks named the same as the cell BE60 on each of the tabs in the Excel file before you run the macro. If you want to add tasks that don't exist, use the `Else` clause--see updated code.

Comment: Got it!  The else statement was needed because it has to overwrite with what could be any text in the box.  I removed the tab looping since it needs to just focus on current active tab, and had to make redundant statements after the 'If' statement to cycle down specific ranges on the sheet.  It makes the code look bulky but since I need specific ranges I don't know if there's a cleaner way to do it.  It only needs to run once, so extra time running the code at execution isn't an issue, it should be fine.  I'll edit my initial message to show the code.  Further improvements welcome.

Comment: I removed the looping through tabs and added a loop for the range on the tab in the Excel file (e.g. every 7 rows starting with row 60). There are other ways to loop through the sections on the excel tab, but this should get you started.

Comment: I thought about doing looping every 7 like that, but it only works for so long then there's a break because it is formatted for printing, so that only works for so long.  Could make multiple loops at 7 lines starting on specific cells, but its still going to be bulky and not really save any time on load.

Comment: Then you can use the Find method in Excel to locate the next range of trial information. See updated code.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great and really cut down the amount of code!  I'll edit the main code at the top of the page to reflect this new update.