# How automatically make Excel cells equal to Project cells?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I have 2 documents, an Excel document and a Microsoft Project document. I want to add an "update" button in the Excel document that will make certain cells equal to certain cells in the Project file.

To some degree, I'm trying to do the opposite of this question: [How can I make a macro in Excel workbook tab to open MS Project and copy reference cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60552888/how-can-i-make-a-macro-in-excel-workbook-tab-to-open-ms-project-and-copy-referen)

Here's the button macro I have so far:
(In this example, one of the tasks/columns in the Project file is "ID", and the desired value I'm trying to make Cell (4,7) equal to exists on another column on the same ID row in the Project file. Having trouble figuring out how to do this.)

```
Sub Update()

projApp As MSProject.Application

Set ProjApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")

projApp.Visible = False

projApp.FileOpenEx "C:\files\project.mpp"

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Inputs").Cells(4,7) = projApp.Find Field:= "ID", Test:="equals", Value:="5748"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will open a Project file, search for a task by ID, then transfer data from that task to the Excel file. The important thing here is that the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.find) method returns True/False and not a reference to the found task.

```
Sub Update()

Dim projApp As MSProject.Application
Dim iOpened As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
Set projApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
If projApp Is Nothing Then
    Set projApp = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
    iOpened = True
End If
projApp.Visible = True

projApp.FileOpenEx "C:\files\project.mpp"


If projApp.Find(Field:="ID", Test:="equals", Value:="5748") Then

    Dim t As MSProject.Task
    Set t = projApp.ActiveCell.Task
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Inputs").Cells(4, 7) = t.Finish
    
End If

projApp.FileCloseEx pjDoNotSave
If iOpened Then
    projApp.Quit pjDoNotSave
End If

End Sub
```

Notes:

- This code does not depend on whether the Project application is already open or not (GetObject vs CreateObject).
- Until the code works flawlessly, it's best to ensure the automated application is visible (Project, in this case).

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks for your help! I'm getting this error referencing "MSProject.Application" and "MSProject.Task" in the code above: "Compile error: User-defined type not defined"

Also, I forgot to mention that the task/column where the desired cell in Project exists is called "Start" (The date when an assigned resource is scheduled to begin). So my desired value exists on the row with ID 5748 and under the "Start" column of that row. Not sure how to incorporate that in your code above.

Also I'm a bit confused about what t is and what t.Finish would be.

Comment: The code (including your original code) presumes [early binding](http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2018/09/vba-referencing-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/), so set a reference to the MS Office Project library (Tools: References). `t` is declared as a [Task object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task) which has many properties including Start, so just change Finish to Start.